# Get rid of numberpad using code and putting number limit on field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a textfield where the keyboard type is number pad.

I used to have this method which was connected to touching anywhere on my view. The connection was made in the xib file. It worked without problem.

```
-(IBAction)closeKeypad:(id)sender
{


[textField1 resignFirstResponder];
[textField2 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

I then needed to put a limit on the the value a user can enter (max of 100).

I ended up with the following.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    //if value is greater than 100, display error message//
    int integer = [textField.text intValue]; //convert value into integer//




    if (integer > 100) {

    UIAlertView *tooHigh = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid" message:@"Number    cannot be over 100" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];


    [tooHigh show];

}
```

Now I need 2 things

1) If the user enters a figure over 100, the text field is cleared and the keyboard stays in that textfield.

2) A way to get rid of the keyboard when touching the background. I'm guessing I need a code based solution?

With the previous implementation, I could enter 200 and then I would get the error but the keyboard would close and 200 would be in the text field.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are having two different problems, you will probably get much better answers if you make this two different questions.  Otherwise, someone who only knows how to answer one part may not answer because you will not be able to "award" the answer as the correct one since it only answers one of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a number formatter, first of all allocate it and set it's main properties:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNUmberFormatter* formatter;
```

In the implementation:

```
self.formatter=[NSNUmberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.maximum= @100;
```

Then :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    NSNumber* value;
    BOOL correct=[formatter getObjectValue: &value forString: self.textField.text errorDescription: nil];
    if(!correct)
    {
        self.textField.text= @""; // clear text
    }
}
```

As for the second part, enable user interaction in the view controller:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
```

Then implement this method:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

You will get notified only if a view that can't become first responder is touched, so resign the first responder of the text field:

```
if(textField.isFirstResponder)
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure where to type this part of the code.

self.formatter=[NSNUmberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.maximum= @100;

Comment: In the viewDidLoad method of your view controller.

Comment: xcode is giving me an error. It wants formatter to be _formatter

Why is that?

Comment: My fault, i didnt synthesise, all sorted now.

Comment: I'm unsure about how I should be using the answer you gave for the second question. I've enabled userinteraction.

The Method you've asked me to implement, what's the actual code in the method?

Where do I put if(textField.isFirstResponder)
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

Sorry if these are really basic questions, still learning. Thanks

Comment: It says textField is an undeclared identifier. Also, where would I call this method?

Comment: This method is a callback: it gets called for you when there is a touch.Synthesize textField or access to self.textField.

Answer (score 0):

As far as dismissing the soft keyboard, you can send the following message to your view, from within the view's View Controller class, and it will dismiss the keyboard:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

One way to get this to fire when a user touches the background, is to add a tap event to the view, and put the above message in the tap gesture event handler.